# swift: how to add price of items in list together

Tags: swift

I am trying to add the prices of all items in a list together.

I declared a class called shoppingBag, and this contains the name, size, and price of each individual item.

I have created a list, myBag, that contains a handful of items and their shoppingBag class data.

```
var myBag= [shoppingBag(name: "tshirt", size: "small", price: 10), shoppingBag(name: "tshirt", size: "medium", price: 10), shoppingBag(name: "tshirt", size: "large", price: 10)]
```

How do I add all of the prices of each item together? Here is the code I have for my class:

```
class shoppingBag {

var name: String = ""
var size: String = ""
var price: Int = 0

init(name: String, size: String, price: Int){
    self.name = name
    self.size = size
    self.price = price
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The following variable `total` contains the sum of all prices in the `myBag` array:

```
let total = myBag.compactMap { $0.price }.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
```

`myBag.compactMap { $0.price }` transforms the array of `shoppingBag` in a simple array of `price`s: `$0` refers to each element, the closure uses only the `.price` of each, so with this command you find only an array of `Int` values.

`.reduce()` is a function which takes all values of the array and provides a single result by applying the function in the closure. `.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }` means that the operation starts with an initial value of "0", then - for each element - performs the calculation inside the closure:

"current value of the result" (the first parameter of the equation, `$0`)

plus

"value of the element" (the second parameter of the equation, `$1`).

For more info:

- [compactMap()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap)
- [reduce()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce)

Comment: thank you for your note but that did not work?

Comment: @m743290: can you tell me what went wrong using that code? Did you get an error message, or is the result not correct, or maybe I misunderstood the request?

Comment: It worked! I just re-implemented it and there were no problmes. I apologize but thank you so much for your help!

Comment: can you help me understand how this function works?

Comment: See edited version above with the explanation.